# MySQL length() result does not match actual number of characters in the column

Tags: mysql, pentaho-data-integration, salesforce-service-cloud

I am updating and inserting records in a Salesforce table using Pentaho Data Integration 9.3. The target column in Salesforce has a maximum length of 32768.

The data is coming from a MySQL 8.0.24 table, from a column (Dev_Comment) with a MEDIUMTEXT data type with a latin1 character set. Certain records are erroring out with "data value too large" error message. When I look at the length of these records in MySQL, both length() and char_length() return 32767. However, when I copy the contents of the field in question and paste it into a text editor (Notepad++), it shows the value as being 33066 characters! And, using substring(Dev_Comment, 1, 32767), the returned value is the same, and also appears to have 33066 characters.

So, I have to arbitrarily shorten the string that I send to the Salesforce update/insert. This makes no sense to me. Any suggestions on why the values produced by length() and char_length() would show one thing, while the value copied to a text editor would show something different?

I have tried columns with different character sets. utf8mb4 produces length() and char_length() values that are different (not surprising). substring(Dev_Comment, 1, 32767) produces something with more bytes than 32767 and which then also causes an error in Pentaho/Salesforce. Latin1 makes length() and char_length() equal in length, but substring() still produces what it thinks is a string of 32767 characters but which is actually 33066.

Comment: One further note: I notice that the difference between the reported length and what I am seeing in the text editor is 299. There are 300 lines in the text when pasted into the editor, and exactly 299 CR/LF characters. Does MySQL perhaps not count the CR/LF characters when returning a value for length()?

Comment: MEDIUMTEXT has a maximum length of 16MB. Why do you think it has a maximum length of 32767?

Comment: MySQL will count cr lf as two characters.  But perhaps there are only lf characters and notepad or your clipboard are "helpfully" changing it to cr lf.

Comment: Select `hex(columnname)` to see what is actually there

Comment: What is it that is giving the "data value too large" error?  Seems like that's where you need to start looking.

Comment: @BillKarwin I don't think that it does. Regardless of the capacity of the source field, the length of the value is showing as 32767 (which should fit in the Salesforce column at the other end). I have updated the value in MySQL using regexp_replace to get rid of all CR/LF characters. Length() still shows it as 32767, and when I copy the value into a text editor, it now actually shows a character count of 32767. So at least now it shows the same length. However, my Pentaho Salesforce Update step is still producing the error stating that the value is too long.

Comment: @ysth I am guessing that the problem lies in the Pentaho Salesforce Update Step and its interpretation of the value. I am pretty sure now that they value is in fact 32767 characters in length. Using hex() produces a string of 65,534 (in hex codes), exactly twice the 32767.

Comment: So it seems like that process is either adding some extra data or encoding some characters (whether in some multi byte character set or uri encoding or html entities or something else).  Compare the source and result values and see if you can figure out what is happening

Comment: It looks like the Pentaho Update Step/Salesforce SOAP API will only take 32728 (40 fewer than the documented maximum length of the value) for the column in question. I can work/live with that, however it is troubling because I cannot find any mention of this happening anywhere, so I am thinking something is amiss. I am continuing to look.